# two level dynamic nested route

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want to achieve two level dynamic nested route in nextJS 13.
I want to implement an add edit form which basically will be for both add and edit
right now the add is like this, for example:

```
/[id]/page.tsx
```

but I also want the edit to have the same code, and have it under a nested two level route, which is optional like this:

```
/[id]/[optionalId]/page.tsx
```

and these two pages should have the same code, but the [optinalId] is not required, as it is for editing.

if I use the catch-all it must be last part of the URL but I already have page.tsx. it is built like this:

```
(user)/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userIId]/page.tsx
```

also have

```
(user)/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userId]/escort/addEdit/page.tsx
```

and want to have

```
(user)/dsahboard/profile/trainee/[userId]/escort/[escortId]/page.tsx
```

Which will have the same code as the last one. I cant use [..userId] as it already has page.tsx of its own.

Edit:

When I tried adding [[slug]] I got the following error

```
Error: You cannot define a route with the same specificity as a optional catch-all route ("/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userId]" and "/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userId][[...slug]]").
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you simplify and clarify your question? Surely all of `(user)/dashboard/profilee/trainee/[userIID]/addEdit/page.tsx` is not essential to the problem? You want 2 path parameters, one of which is optional?

Comment: the (user)/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userId]/addEdit/page.tsx is essential, thats for adding. I want to add editing which be optional abd should be (user)/dashboard/profile/trainee/[userId]/addEdit/[escortId]/page.tsx

Comment: It's not essential to the problem, the problem would be the same with `/[id]/page.tsx` and `/[id]/[optionalId]/page.tsx` but your question would be a lot clearer. A run on block of text barely ever receives any answers. Your question needs to be visually clear at a glance to answer. Try to drop a lot of the detail you give that we don't need, and rewrite it with a clear question and a code block with the routes you want to have, and someone that understands the nextjs router can help you within a minute :)

Comment: Sadly I thought this was a NeStJS question and I would have answered it myself ;p

Comment: II changed the question thanks mate